# How are native objects implemented in browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Whenever we declare

```
var item = "string";
```

It means we are creating a string variable but surely a string object is made in background so that we can access

```
item.length;
```

It means `item` has reference to some object so we can access it's property.

It is confusing because `item.length` tempts me to consider `item` as a reference to an object but if we log it on console it just prints it value.

Someone please can help me?

Comment: please, what's the question? do you want to understand why we can manage item as an object but it's not an object?

Comment: Yes exactly....it is a variable....but how come we can use it as an object to reference string object properties like length